# How to get keccak-256sum command in ubuntu

Tags: command-line

I am not sure whether this is the right platform to ask but let's give it a shot.

How to get `keccak-256sum` command in linux terminal? The Ubuntu already has commands like `md5sum,sha256sum,sha384sum,ha512sum` commands but not `keccak`.

I have not found this in ubuntu package-manager. Is there any third party liberary that allows me to get such command?

Comment: @andrew.46 does not add it for me

Answer (score 0):

> [SHA-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-3) is a subset of the broader cryptographic primitive family **Keccak**.

Try using `openssl` command, e.g.

```
$ printf test | openssl dgst -sha3-256
SHA3-256(stdin)= 36f028580bb02cc8272a9a020f4200e346e276ae664e45ee80745574e2f5ab80
```

Pipe into `awk '{print $NF}'` to extract only the hash value.

See also:

- [Difference between keccak256 and sha3](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/30369/105)
- [What are the key differences between the draft SHA-3 standard and the Keccak submission?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15727/2592)